# Oracle Apex: dropped objects don't appear in recycle bin

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, restore, recycle-bin, flashback

After accidentally dropping a package body in Oracle Application Express 4.0.2.00.09, I tried to restore it from the recycle bin.

The object however does not appear in that folder, along with other numerous objects I have dropped in the past.

Using Flashback has had no effect either. Has anyone else ever experienced this? Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Just restore it from your version control software.

Answer (score 1):

The recyclebin only stores dropped tables (and their associated bits and pieces like indexes and triggers).

Database packages, views and other objects are dropped permanently. You need to restore from a backup or version control software.